# Modifying Leaflet Popups in R

Tags: css, r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I want to modify the appearance of leaflet popups in R.

The helpfile states that `...` in the `popupOptions()` function takes
"extra options passed to underlying Javascript object constructor."

In [this example](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html), the `style` option is set to a list of CSS parameters that modify the appearance of markers:

```
  addMarkers(
    lng = -118.456554, lat = 34.075,
    label = "Label w/ custom CSS style",
    labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, direction = "bottom",
      style = list(
        "color" = "red",
        "font-family" = "serif",
        "font-style" = "italic",
        "box-shadow" = "3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25)",
        "font-size" = "12px",
        "border-color" = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
      )))
```

However, the same approach does not seem to work with Popups, as this minimal working example demonstrates:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(leaflet, eurostat, dplyr)

map <- get_eurostat_geospatial() %>% subset(., .$NUTS_ID == "AT11")

leaflet() %>%

  addPolygons(data = map , 
              group = map$NUTS_ID,
              fillColor = "grey",
              weight = 1,
              color = "black") %>%

  addPopups(lng = 16.3, lat = 47, popup = "Paint it black!",
            options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE,
                                   opacity = 0.5,
                                   style = list("background" = "black",
                                                "padding" = "2px",
                                                "border-radius" = "0px")))
```

Some webpages explain the customization of the labels with CSS using the javascript version of Leaflet (e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/uafrazier/d589caa322f1b1e7c651)). The key seems to be to edit `.leaflet-popup-tip` and `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper`. But how can I do this in `R` (not using Shiny)?

Related: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310921/getting-finer-control-of-leaflet-popups-in-r) question, which however only addresses modifying elements within a popup and not popups themselves.

I welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you could use the package `htmltools` to get what you want.

```
map2 <- leaflet() %>%
    addPolygons(data = map , 
                group = map$NUTS_ID,
                fillColor = "grey",
                weight = 1,
                color = "black") %>%
    addPopups(lng = 16.3, lat = 47, popup = "Paint it black!")

library(htmltools)
browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        ".leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    background: black;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2px;
border-radius: 0px;
    }
        "
      )
    ),
    map2
  ))
)
```