# R code to save shiny.tag.list to html as the viewer->export->save as web page button does

Tags: r, r-leaflet, r-mapview, htmltools

I have a leaflet map that I have modified to have a special CSS for popups following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232324/modifying-leaflet-popups-in-r). Now I want to save the result as an HTML web page. The resulting object is of type `shiny.tag.list`, which I can view with the viewer and export to HTML by hand using the `Export->Save as web page` button. However, I cannot find the R code to do this same operation. I have tried the `mapshot` function in the `mapview` package and the `saveWidget` function in `htmltools`, but these fail with the error:

```
> saveWidget(lf,"test.html")
Error in .getNamespace(pkg) : 
 invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation
```

I have also tried the `save_html` function of the `htmltools` package, but this generates an HTML file that is not standalone.

How do I do exactly what the `Export->Save as web page` button does with R code?

Here is some sample code to demonstrate the issues:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(mapview)

x = data.frame(lat=c(44,45),lon=c(3,2),
               label=c("p1","p2"))

x = st_as_sf(x,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)

lf = x %>% leaflet %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(label=~label,popup=~label)
st = browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(".leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {background-color: #ff0000;}")
    ),
    lf
  ))
)

saveWidget(st,"test.html") # Fails with error
mapshot(st,"test.html") # Fails with same error
save_html(st,"test.html") # Produces HTML with external dependencies
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and solved it with `htmlwidgets::prepandContent`

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(mapview)
library(htmlwidgets)

x = data.frame(lat=c(44,45),lon=c(3,2),
               label=c("p1","p2"))

x = st_as_sf(x,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)

lf = x %>% leaflet %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(label=~label,popup=~label)


st = lf %>% prependContent(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(".leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {background-color: #ff0000;}")
    )
    )

saveWidget(st,"test.html") # works!
```